# Decorate behaviour of subclass methods of an abstract base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have an inheritance scenario that looks like this:

```
import abc


class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, x: int | None = None) -> None:
        self.x = x

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self, x: int | None = None) -> None:
        pass


class B(A):
    def foo(self, x: int | None = None) -> None:
        x = x or self.x
        if x is None:
            raise ValueError("x must be defined")

        print(x)


class C(B):
    ...  # defines a bunch of other stuff
```

The idea is that it will be possible for users (other developers) to use my class in two different ways. Either they interact directly with `B` (or another equivalent subclass of `A`) and then they have to pass certain values to its methods (in this case, they need to pass `x` to the `B.foo` method. Alternatively, they can instead subclass `B` (like `C` in this example) and then set `x` directly in the init and then subsequently there is no need to pass `x` to `C.foo`.

In the end, both of these usages should be valid:

```
b = B()
b.foo(x=1)

c = C(x=1)
c.foo()
```

Now, the problem is that I would like to avoid having to repeat this clause in different methods and different subclasses of `A`:

```
x = x or self.x
if x is None:
    ValueError("x must be defined")
```

Is there any way I can do something in `A` that will essentially run this check, and effectively pass the along the value of `x` to the `foo` method if it has not been given a value for `x`?

I would essentially want to make `self.x` the default value for `x`, but I don't want to have to re-write the `if x is None` check if I can avoid it.

Something that comes to mind would be if I could somehow automatically register a decorator onto the methods of my subclass, but I don't think that it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `foo` you want to override, it's a method used *by* `foo`.

Let's start by updating `A`.

```
class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, x: int | None = None) -> None:
        self.x = x

    def foo(self, x: int | None = None) -> None:
        if x is None:
            if self.x is None:
                raise ValueError("x must be provided")
            x = self.x
        self.foo_work(x)

    @abstractmethod
    def foo_work(self, x: int) -> None:
        ...
```

Note that `foo_work` *must* receive an `x`; it won't accept `None` as an argument. But that's OK, because your end user will never call `foo_work` directly: they will only call `foo`, which either finds a valid argument for `foo_work` or raises an exception.

```
class B(A):
    def foo_work(self, x: int) -> None:       
        print(x)


B().foo()  # ValueError
B(1).foo()  # OK
B().foo(1)  # OK
```

---

This might seem a little awkward: you have what is essentially an implementation detail of `A` being exposed as part of its public interface. This stems from the fact that `foo` is really two methods being forced together into one:

1. One that takes a value as an argument
2. One that takes a value from its own internal state

Arguably, you should keep the two separate:

```
class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, x: int = None):
        self.x = x

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self, x: int) -> None:
        ...

    def foo_with_default(self) -> None:
        if self.x is None:
            raise ValueError("x must be defined")
        return self.foo(self.x)
```

Now, both methods are part of the public interface, subclasses are required to implement `foo`, and `foo_with_default` is essentially final and should not be overridden (though `abc` doesn't provide a way to mark it as such). The cost is that the end-user must be aware of which function to use.

Comment: ahhh so simple, thanks - exactly what I wanted!